# What does {:literal} mean in a Google search?

Tags: google-search

I searched for [Adam Sandler](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=adam%20sandler) today and I saw this:
[image: {:literal}]

I couldn't find anything in [Google search docs](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) about `{:literal}` search operator. Any idea why I might've seen this and what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

That should be a [glitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch) or something related to the browser and/or extensions that you are using.